# How to return error code from the main function in C++?

Tags: c++, error-handling

I am working on an object-oriented C++ coursework where I need to return error codes from the main function. How would one do this properly?

Unfortunately this is an assessed coursework so I cannot post my code here. But let's say the case is as follows:

I'm building an enigma machine with classes Plugboard, Reflector, and Rotor. I pass each of the configuration files as arguments in the command line. In this task, I'm provided with a file errors.h containing the following:

```
#define INSUFFICIENT_NUMBER_OF_PARAMETERS       1
#define INVALID_INPUT_CHARACTER                 2
#define INVALID_INDEX                           3
// and so on...
```

So I have in my program several functions to check the errors, for example a function to check whether the configuration file contains an invalid character (it has to be 0 to 25). I was thinking of setting this as a boolean function and then in my main function have the following:

```
if (!plugboard.check_invalid_character(/*some arguments*/)) {
   cerr << "Invalid character!" << endl;
   return 2;
}
```

But I'm not completely sure this is the right way to do it? Is it too superficial? Is there a more elegant way of returning error?

I hope my question is a little clearer this time. Thanks before.

Comment: Can you please post the relevant code? The error codes will only go as far as they are returned, if they are not returned into the main function, and then returned at the end of main, then no, the program will not abort.

Comment: If I were you, for readability purposes, I would use `INVALID_INPUT_CHARACTER` instead of `2` to improve readability (and so the code looks slightly more impressive to a non-programmer!) for a variety of reasons, including that the header file *might* be substituted at any time, or the error codes could need changing. **Don't use magic numbers.**

Answer (score 3):

You just need to return the value 4 in your main method like this:

```
int main() {
    return 4;
}
```

Please note that your main function could also have the arguments vector and the argument count so there could be more in the brackets.

If KLibby is right and you use a method with returns the value you need to use something like that:

```
int doSomething() {
    return 4;
}

int main() {
    return doSomething();
}
```

Comment: I think the OP is getting these return codes from functions _other_ than main, and wants to know how to return them back to main.

Comment: In that case he has to return the value to that return statement, but since he has no example code this is a little hard to guess.

Comment: That's why I asked them for the code :)